Brew Dependency Issues - Python@3.12
Hey so I have been facing this issue since the past few months and I have had to always use docker to install something rather than brew due to this issue:
Note:

I am not sure if this is deemed as a No Fix available, from what i saw I do not see any posts related to it.
I was reinstalling php just to clear out any updates and have been experiencing it with almost all the packages i am installing.

make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5
Last 15 lines from /Users/admin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python@3.12/03.make:
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_socket.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/syslog.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/syslog.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/termios.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/termios.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_posixshmem.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_posixshmem.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_multiprocessing.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_ctypes.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_curses.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_curses.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_curses_panel.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_sqlite3.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_ssl.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_hashlib.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_uuid.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_uuid.cpython-312-darwin.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 Modules/_tkinter.cpython-312-darwin.so /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-312-darwin.so
install: Modules/_tkinter.cpython-312-darwin.so: No such file or directory
make: *** [sharedinstall] Error 71

I've done these:
> brew reinstall python@3.12
> brew reinstall tcl-tk

I've also restarted my machine, ran brew cleanup and brew doctor.

System info: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

PS: I am aware of this:
Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.

But i still need a fix for it so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
